# Annotating resource to produce JSON, but return "text/plain" in response header

Tags: java, json, spring, jersey, cors

I am currently implementing a web API

- Spring
- Jersey
- com.thetransactioncompany.cors http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html

The output (if any) will be JSON, so all my classes are annotated with the expected media type.

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class CustomerResource {
    ...
}
```

that way my classes are automatically transformed to *json*.

BUT...

Due to microsoft, their IE only support CORS, if the request/response type is *text/plain* http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

```
4. Only text/plain is supported for the request's Content-Type header
```

so I need to force my application to respond with *text/plain* in the header but still projecting my classes to *json* output. I know that the CORS classes I added is setting that header, but somehow that is overwritten again by my annotation, even if I add another filter by my own.

Comment: A good question! Do you need to serve up the resource as a _real_ `text/plain` to any clients or can you live with telling lies for good reasons? :-)

Comment: I can live with telling lies for the good reason, that IE otherwise would not completely support CORS. I expect the frontend to not trust that response header but to know, what to expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hum, the link you are pointing says that it is true for **REQUESTS** only.
So you can accept only text plain but are free to produce what ever you want.

**EDIT** Try registering a custom responsefilter with code similar to that (maybe you already did it?):

```
@Provider
public class HeaderRewriteFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
   @Override
   public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response)  {
     response.setResponse(Response
                .fromResponse(response.getResponse()).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain").build());
             return response;
  }
}
```

However check the result to ensure it is ok if the response already contains this header.
Otherwise you can try to modify the current response, but I am not sure you can as it might be an immutable object. And by the way it looks less clean to me :)

```
List<Object> contentTypes = response.getHttpHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
contentTypes.clear();
contentTypes.add("text/plain");
```

Also for doing json<>java databiding you can check Genson library http://code.google.com/p/genson/, it integrates well with Jersey. Just drop the jar in the classpath and run!

**EDIT 2** OK then you must do it in the other way, use produces "text/plain" and define a json bodywriter for for that type. Downside is that you will be able to produce only json. With Genson you could do it that way:

```
@Provider
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN })
public class PlainTextJsonConverter extends GensonJsonConverter {
    public GensonJsonConverter() {
       super();
    }

    public GensonJsonConverter(@javax.ws.rs.core.Context Providers providers) {
       super(providers);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok the second link may be a bit misleading, but it is mentioned, that you also should have all your responses set to text/plain in IE. I fixed the questions, thanks

Comment: @MatthiasLaug I have updated my answer, try it, this should work

Comment: I've used [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) before to serialize POJOs to strings with good results. It's what's used under the covers by JBoss' RESTeasy. You could do this and keep 'text/plain' in the response header.

Comment: Yes, I using Jackson, annotated my class so that once I return that class in an action, it will result in json. But to trigger that I need to annotate my method with @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

Comment: @MatthiasLaug ok, did you try one of the solutions? Does it work? If not check if you don't have some filter or other code that forces the response content type to json

Comment: I registered a Filter and added httpResponse.setHeader(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain"); the result sadly are two content-type headers, so I need to find out, how to remove the first one that is added by the annotation

Comment: tried that as well, but I get the expected error, that jersey does not know how to map the returned class in my action: A message body writer for Java class xxx, and Java type class xxx, and MIME media type text/plain was not found

Comment: @MatthiasLaug ok, I have updated my response. Try this last solution, you can of corse make it more modular to support other types, but thats the idea. Here is an example on how to implement a bodywriter/reader http://code.google.com/p/genson/source/browse/src/main/java/com/owlike/genson/ext/jersey/GensonJsonConverter.java

Comment: You might want to update this great answer for jersey 2 and mention how to register the provider.